# xml de-serialization with a very simple file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, xml-serialization, .net-4.5

I just started with xml serialization and I tried these:

(1) throws an exception while deserializing.
(2) also throws an exception
(3) not working as it should be.

Any ideas is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
  1) const string XML = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
                    <DietPlan>
                            <Fruit>fig</Fruit>
                            <Veggie>Carrot</Veggie>
                    </DietPlan>";

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DietPlan")]
    public class TestData
    {
        [XmlElement("Fruit")]
        public XmlElement Fruits { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Veggie")]
        public XmlElement test { get; set; }  

    }



 2) const string XML = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
                    <DietPlan>
                            <Fruit>fig</Fruit>
                            <Fruit>fig</Fruit>
                            <Veggie>Carrot</Veggie>
                            <Veggie>Carrot</Veggie>
                    </DietPlan>";

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DietPlan")]
    public class TestData
    {
        [XmlElement("Fruit")]
        public List<XmlElement> Fruits { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Veggie")]
        public List<XmlElement> test { get; set; }  

    }


3) const string XML = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
                    <DietPlan>
                        <Data>
                            <Fruit>fig</Fruit>
                            <Fruit>fig</Fruit>
                            <Veggie>Carrot</Veggie>
                            <Veggie>Carrot</Veggie>
                        </Data>
                    </DietPlan>";

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DietPlan")]
    public class TestData
    {
        public Datas Datas { get; set; }

    }

public class Datas
{
    [XmlElement("Fruit")]
    public List<XmlElement> Fruits { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Veggie")]
    public List<XmlElement> test { get; set; }  
}
```

1) The xml files are valid in my context! (though not on the correct format)

2) this is the code i use to de-serialize!

```
public static void Deserialize()
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XML));
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestData));
        var obj = (TestData)xs.Deserialize(ms);

    }
```

EDIT: (3) already has an answer here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907357/deserialization-of-xml-file-by-using-xmlarray?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need your class members to be of type XMLElement, use string instead:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "DietPlan")]
public class TestData
{
    [XmlElement("Fruit")]
    public string Fruits { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Veggie")]
    public string test { get; set; }

}
```