# XML deserialization failed to load values to element containing array of elements

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestConfiguration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Barcode>MB-B3-00</Barcode>
    <TestSuites>
        <Test>USB A Slave Port</Test>
        <Test>USB B Host Port</Test>
    </TestSuites>
</TestConfiguration>
```

I want to deserialize it into the following class:

```
 public class TestConfiguration
    {
        private string _barcode;
        private string[] _testSuites;
        private string[] _testcase;

        //Product barcode
        public string Barcode
        {
            get{return this._barcode;}
            set{this._barcode = value;}
        }       

        //Test suites
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Test", IsNullable = false)]       
        public string[] Testsuites
        {
            get{return this._testSuites;}
            set{this._testSuites = value;}
        }

        //individual test
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public string[] Testcase
        {
            get{return this._testcase;}
            set{this._testcase = value;}
        }
    }
```

My deserialization code is:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestConfiguration));
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
TestConfiguration _testConfig = (TestConfiguration)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```

However, `_testConfig` object only contains Barcode value and the properties `Testcase` and `TestSuites` are null.  Any advice please?

Comment: You're using XmlArrayAttribute incorrectly - see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907357/deserialization-of-xml-file-by-using-xmlarray.  You'll need to define another class to do what you're tyring to do.

Comment: What does the XML look like if you manually populate the class, and then serialize it into XML?

Comment: What value(s) are you expecting to see in `Testcase`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.  The name of your property, `Testsuites`, doesn't *quite* match the name of the element `<TestSuites>` - the capitalization of the letter `S` differs, and [XML Tags are Case Sensitive](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp).

To fix, rename the property or attach an [`XmlArrayAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the correct [element name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
    //Test suites
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArray("TestSuites")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("Test", IsNullable = false)]
    public string[] Testsuites
    {
        get { return this._testSuites; }
        set { this._testSuites = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  You can eliminate the tag  and have an array of just  element.  I can show you how.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestConfiguration));
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            TestConfiguration _testConfig = (TestConfiguration)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();

        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("TestConfiguration")]
    public class TestConfiguration
    {
        private string _barcode;
        private string[] _testSuites;
        private string[] _testcase;

        //Product barcode
        [XmlElement("Barcode")]
        public string Barcode { get; set; }

        //Test suites
        [XmlElement("TestSuites")]
        public TestSuites testSuites { get; set; }

    }
    //individual test
    [XmlRoot("TestSuites")]
    public class TestSuites
    {
        [XmlElement("Test")]
        public List<string> test {get;set;}
    }

}
​
```